# I can't make argparse work

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I want to add arguments through append in parser.add_argument but when I run it the following message appears

```
Prueba.py: error: argument -c1/--col1: expected one argument
```

Even when I tried to access help with `-h` it appears.

Here's the code

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This is a program that makes a comparison between two files')

parser.add_argument('-c1', '--col1', action = 'append', default = [1,2], help = "Numbers in the first column")
parser.add_argument('-c2', '--col2', action = 'append', default = [1,2], help = "Numbers in the second column")

parser.add_argument('-f1', '--file1', type=str, action = 'store', help="File 1 Path")
parser.add_argument('-f2', '--file2', type=str, action = 'store', help="File 2 Path")


parser.parse_args('--col1'.split(','))
parser.parse_args('--col2'.split(','))

args = parser.parse_args()

col1 = args.col1
col2 = args.col2
file1 = args.file1
file2 = args.file2

print file1
print file2
print col1
print col2
```

Comment: `col1` appends a value (an argument). When you run with only `--col`, there **is** no argument. So of **course** your test code passing only `['--col1']` or `['--col2']` (on the following line) fails.

Answer (score 0):

Both `--col1` and `--col2` expect an associated argument. So, you are passing invalid arguments to `parse_args`.

On top of that, your use of `split(',')` is an error. Surely you meant to write `split()`. The error is benign as the code stands in the question. But as soon as you add extra arguments, it breaks down.

Replace the three calls to `parse_args()` to be this single call:

```
args = parser.parse_args('--col1 1 --col2 2'.split())
```

Here's a short demo program to demonstrate a working `append` argument.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--arg', action='append')
print parser.parse_args('--arg foo --arg bar'.split())
```

**Output**

```
Namespace(arg=['foo', 'bar'])
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you remove the lines

```
parser.parse_args('--col1'.split(','))
parser.parse_args('--col2'.split(','))
```

What are they supposed to do anyways? Why are you splitting fixed strings at ',' which are not even containing any ','?

Comment: Well, these calls to `parse_args()` are the entire crux of the question. Sure, the code runs when you remove them, but that's hardly the point. The idea is to test what happens with specific arguments.

Comment: Their presence is the cause of this complaint: `Even when I tried to access help with -h it appears.`

Comment: @hpaulj Obviously they are broken. Using -h won't help because the code ignores the command line arguments. The arguments are specified in code for testing purposes, or for the sake of asking the question. My point is that blanket removal is no good. What is needed is to fix these calls. I showed how to do that.